# mpg123_open() and Const

Tags: c++, char, constants

Im a newbie on c++ programing and im basicly trying to make a simple mp3 player using mpg123, the code works great when in the main() but when i try to call it in a sub and submitting the path+file to play i just cant get it to work.

gcc complains about const char... and char conversion..
"1.c:71:18: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]"

```
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <mpg123.h>

#define BITS 8

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void playaudio(const char * trakl)
{

//works when called here including path
//const char *traklink="/home/pi/downloads/00000050.mp3";
const char * traklink=trakl;



   mpg123_handle *mh;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size;
    size_t done;
    int err;

    int driver;
    ao_device *dev;

    ao_sample_format format;
    int channels, encoding;
    long rate;

   /* if(argc < 2)
        exit(0);
*/
    /* initializations */
    ao_initialize();
    driver = ao_default_driver_id();
    mpg123_init();
    mh = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    buffer_size = mpg123_outblock(mh);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));

    /* open the file and get the decoding format */
    //mpg123_open(mh,traklink);
    mpg123_open(mh,traklink);
     mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    /* set the output format and open the output device */
   format.bits = mpg123_encsize(encoding) * BITS;
    format.rate = rate;
    format.channels = channels;
    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    format.matrix = 0;
    dev = ao_open_live(driver, &format, NULL);

    /* decode and play */
    while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
        //ao_play(dev, buffer, done);
        ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done);
    /* clean up */
    free(buffer);
    ao_close(dev);
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
    ao_shutdown();

//  return 0;
}

int main()
{
const char * trakl="/home/pi/downloads/00000050.mp3";

playaudio(* trakl);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So C or C++? Those are two different languages. Also, make sure to have a basic understanding of the language before trying to make a complex application such as a media player. At least know what pointers and arrays are and what the `*` operator does.

Comment: @H2CO3: Is it possible to make a media player app using c/c++?

Comment: @MiguelC It is possible to write an application in **either** C or C++, if that's what you are asking. There's no such language as C/C++, and it is at best undesired, and sometimes even impossible to mix the two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `playaudio` like this:

```
playaudio(* trakl);
```

This is invalid. `trak1` is of type `const char *`, this implies that `*trak1` is of type `const char`. `playaudio` expects a `const char *`, you should call it like this instead:

```
playaudio(trakl);
```

Comment: Great I knew i was near an answer but didnt think of that until i read your post. , Works Great, thanks @Filipe